# What happens when CSS children percentage of width is more than 100%

Tags: css

I have a table that fills dynamically with columns based on the dataset it receives. Each column gets a width of 15%. Sometimes there are 10 columns which is technically over 100%. What is the expected outcome?

Background: I am trying to add excel like column resizing and when I resize one column the other columns shrink and seem like they are trying to compensate. I don't want them to, I also don't want them static. So, I'm just curious if having  % widths is causing the bugs.

Note: please do not recommend any plugin's. Just curious about the CSS.

Comment: Perhaps this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934695/css-width-above-100) and the answers there will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the user agent. The spec states that user agents may choose to reflow the layout but does not define exactly how it must be done. Some of them will just automatically divide 100% by the number of cols and reflow them. Some browsers will arbitrarily narrow one or more of the colums to fit. Some will just keep them at the defined width and push excess to the next row. Basically, there is no guarantee of the behavior, so I would not even set width implicitly if you dont know the number of columns/items in advance.

You could just populate them all, then use a bit of JS to divide 100% by the number of cols and use that value to update the CSS on the fly to reflow.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense of it. The project I'm on is using the ng-Table directive in Angular 1.x and using a resizable directive on top of that so it's pretty convoluted. I just so happen to be the developer chosen to maintain the code and I'm trying to make the css work well with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are displayed as block elements, they wrap onto a new line (in firefox):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  background: red;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">abc</div>
  <div class="item">abc</div>
</div>
```

However, if you're using actual tables (or `display: table`), they behave differently:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  background: red;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<table class="container">
  <tr>
    <td class="item">abc</td>
    <td class="item">abc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not an expert on `table` behavior, feel free to edit this answer or create a new answer based on this one.